# sound design for spritekit with swift

Tags: ios, audio, swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to figure out how to add some sound design elements to my game.  For example.. I want an engine sound to change pitch or grow louder as my sprite moves faster.  Obviously this is outside the scope of `SKAction`.  I've tried `AVAudioPlayer`..  this works but it seems to be more suited towards playing music.  Even running a short loop using `AVAudioPlayer` produces popping sounds between each loop.

How can I control things like pitch, volume, playback speed programmatically?

This seems useful.

http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/index.html

but is there a swift version..  or can I bridge this over to swift somehow.

Comment: You can seamlessly integrate ObjC with Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/

Comment: If you really want to go nuts, there's a port of [Pure Data](http://puredata.info)'s [libpd](https://github.com/libpd) for iOS. I'm just going through [this book](https://pragprog.com/book/thsound/programming-sound-with-pure-data) right now. Warning: Pure Data's design interface looks like someone's university project from 1991. It's utterly awful. But it does work and allow you to completely synthesise sound from scratch with dynamic realtime control.

Comment: About the loop thing... there are a couple of workarounds that are very usefull:
1) Use uncompressed audio for short loops, they behave better since they do not need of decompressing before adding data into buffer, thus using less cpu, they take more space but sound better and behave nice.
2) Use a blank (silence) sound and loop it always in the background, this will keep the audio engine always ready and available.

Hope it helps, and remember that they are workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

[ObjectAL](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ObjectAL-for-iPhone) can be added as a Pod into a Swift project, i am using it right now in my own Swift projects.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  in the end i bridged object al over to swift and it worked ok for my project.  bit of a learning curve though.  looking forward to the next version of spritekit

Comment: @hamobi , no problem, i was trying to bridge it too! but without any luck, do you happen to have some kind of sample project with objectAl bridged?

Comment: i cant share my whole project but from what I recall i just followed instructions in adding objectal from the site (adding required frameworks) and i added these to my bridging header

#import "ObjectAL.h"
#import "ObjectALConfig.h"